# The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file

Tags: c#

I am using the "File"  attribute of AppSettings but I am getting this error

> The root element must match the name
>   of the section referencing the file,
>   'appSettings'

Well I am adding a ClassLibrary1.dll and ClassLibrary1.dll.config in my windows project.
Ny windows application is having its own `app.config`

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings file="ClassLibrary1.dll.config"> 
    <add key="main" value="main"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

thankx in advance

Comment: well i dont know how to accept the answer actually i am very new here,well there is one more prob... this works in case if i am having one exernal config file,what in the case if i am having more then one external  config file

Comment: Reposting my comment here: In that case, I think you should rethink your design. Based on your filename "ClassLibrary1.dll.config", I assume your approach is to have multiple class libraries, each one with its own "config" file to override the appSettings section in your executable's config file. It sounds to me like each class library has its own set of settings stored in appSettings. Instead, try creating custom config sections for your class libraries to keep each library's settings separate. You can then use the configSource attribute, which is similar to the appSettings file attribute.

Comment: slash shogdhe: ok, and now please accept the answer that helped you most solve your problem - it's the right thing to do on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my follow-up answer based on the OP's recent comment: What if I have more than one external config file?

My suggestion is to revise the design of the configuration settings. I assume that you have multiple class libraries, and each class library has its own set of settings that are currently being stored in the appSettings section.  In that case, your config file probably looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- App Settings for Class Library 1 -->
    <add key="ClassLibrary1Value1" value="123"/>
    <add key="ClassLibrary1Value2" value="234"/>
    <add key="ClassLibrary1Value3" value="345"/>
    <!-- App Settings for Class Library 2 -->
    <add key="ClassLibrary2Value1" value="ABC"/>
    <add key="ClassLibrary2Value2" value="BCD"/>
    <add key="ClassLibrary2Value3" value="CDE"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and your code for accessing those settings might look something like this:

```
        var appSettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        Console.WriteLine(appSettings["ClassLibrary1Value1"]);
        Console.WriteLine(appSettings["ClassLibrary1Value2"]);
        Console.WriteLine(appSettings["ClassLibrary1Value3"]);

        Console.WriteLine(appSettings["ClassLibrary2Value1"]);
        Console.WriteLine(appSettings["ClassLibrary2Value2"]);
        Console.WriteLine(appSettings["ClassLibrary2Value3"]);
```

Instead, I suggest you try separating each class library's settings into its own config section.  You could accomplish this by modifying your executable's config file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="classLibrary1" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
    <section name="classLibrary2" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
  </configSections>
  <classLibrary1 configSource="ClassLibrary1.dll.config" />
  <classLibrary2 configSource="ClassLibrary2.dll.config" />
</configuration>
```

Your ClassLibrary1.dll.config file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<classLibrary1>
  <add key="Value1" value="123"/>
  <add key="Value2" value="234"/>
  <add key="Value3" value="345"/>
</classLibrary1>
```

Your ClassLibrary2.dll.config file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<classLibrary2>
  <add key="Value1" value="ABC"/>
  <add key="Value2" value="BCD"/>
  <add key="Value3" value="CDE"/>
</classLibrary2>
```

and your code to access these settings would look something like this:

```
        var classLibrary1AppSettings = (System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("classLibrary1");
        Console.WriteLine(classLibrary1AppSettings["Value1"]);
        Console.WriteLine(classLibrary1AppSettings["Value2"]);
        Console.WriteLine(classLibrary1AppSettings["Value3"]);

        var classLibrary2AppSettings = (System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("classLibrary2");
        Console.WriteLine(classLibrary2AppSettings["Value1"]);
        Console.WriteLine(classLibrary2AppSettings["Value2"]);
        Console.WriteLine(classLibrary2AppSettings["Value3"]);
```

Comment: this is fine but i dont want to use this code behind,actually i want somthing like if i write             string[] allkeys = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys; then i will get the keys of all config.....

Comment: In my example you can do `classLibrary1AppSettings.AllKeys` and `classLibrary2AppSettings.AllKeys`. Do you want all of the settings across all of your external config files to be consolidated into a single object so that you can do something like `settings.AllKeys`? I don't think there is any built-in functionality to support something like that, and I would question whether that is a good idea. What if you have two class libraries that use the same key? How would you consolidate those settings?

Comment: Also, the only reason I could imagine that you'd want to do AppSettings.AllKeys is for tracing purposes. Otherwise, if your application doesn't already know what settings should be in the config file, then how would it make use of those settings? If you are using the settings stored in AppSettings without knowing what the keys are, then I would ask yourself whether the settings that you're trying to put into the config file are actually "config settings" or if they are "data".

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice: When I use like your custom config node (classLibrary2), I am getting error that "Unrevognised element "ClassLibrary2". If I add <configuration> node before that I am getting "the root element must match the name of the section referencing the file". Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: @Shesha - I'm not sure what the problem is that you're facing. My only advice is to make sure that 1) you have registered your custom config section within the <configSections> element of your config file, 2) the "<classLibrary2" element name you are using matches the value you specified in the name attribute within the <configSections> element (case-sensitive), and 3) the element name that you're using as the root element within the separate file also matches the value you specified in the name attribute within the <configSections> element.

Answer (score 12):

Your external file must look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="main" value="main"/>
</appSettings>
```

Unlike when you use `configSource`, you can't have a configuration node when using the file attribute. I'm not even 100% sure you can use a configuration node with the configSource attribute, I always match the root node that is being externalized.  See the MSDN documentation for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx

Also, I've never tried to reference an assembly configuration file as you are here. I wonder if that may be causing problems?  Try extracting just the appSettings node to another config file and see if that solves the issue.

edit: This external file (we'll call it appSettings_external.config) can be used in two ways:

app.config: (settings are merged)

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
    <appSettings file="appSettings_external.config">
      <add key="main" value="main"/>
    </appSettings>
   </configuration>
```

app.config: (settings are pulled only from external config)

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
    <appSettings configSource="appSettings_external.config" />
   </configuration>
```

Comment: +1 right on - as the error message **clearly** states: *The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file* ...

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell what's in *ClassLibrary1.dll.config* because he didn't post it ;D

Comment: this works in case if i am having one exernal config file,what in the case if i am having more then one external  config file

Comment: +1 This option worked best for me. The accepted answer worked as well but it doesn't add the keys to the "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" value collection - This one does.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the root XML element in your file "ClassLibrary1.dll.config" is "appSettings".

http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/04/09/5261.aspx

Comment: what does this line means "Make sure that the root XML element in your file "ClassLibrary1.dll.config" is "appSettings".

Comment: this works in case if i am having one exernal config file,what in the case if i am having more then one external  config file

Comment: In that case, I think you should rethink your design.  Based on your filename "ClassLibrary1.dll.config", I assume your approach is to have multiple class libraries, each one with its own "config" file to override the appSettings section in your executable's config file. It sounds to me like each class library has its own set of settings stored in appSettings. Instead, try creating custom config sections for your class libraries to keep each library's settings separate. You can then use the configSource attribute, which is similar to the appSettings file attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The / chars of the end tags seem to be missing:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="ClassLibrary1.dll.config"> 
        <add key="main" value="main" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look on the first result that google give you when you type "The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file"

http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/04/09/5261.aspx

then look for "The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file" in the page

Comment: this works in case if i am having one exernal config file,what in the case if i am having more then one external  config file

Answer (score 0):

Apart from making sure that your external config file does fulfill the requirement specified in the error message (i.e. the root element of the xml should be appSettings) you can also check whether VS isn't reading the old version. When you modify the external config file no recompilation is triggered, so for each change you should also **modify the main web.config** so that it gets refreshed (or at least touch it) .