# Sections must only appear once - appsettings

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, web-config

I'm a bit confused as to how I can specify another .config file in my web.config while retaining parts of the original web config. I want to put my connection strings in another file but when I build the project I get an error about there being multiple `appsettings` elements.

I have this:

```
  <appSettings file="ConnectionStrings.config">
  </appSettings>
```

then further down, because it's a Crystal Reports application, these settings are specified. I don't want these keys in my connnectionstrings.config file as they're not relevant.

```
 <appSettings>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
        <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
    </appSettings>
```

How do I keep my seperate config file and the Crystal settings above, without putting them all in the connectionstrings.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main configuration file(web.config) should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<!--other sections-->
<appSettings file="appSettings.config">
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
</appSettings>
<!--other sections-->
</configuration>
```

Further your separate appSettings.config should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="YourConnectionStringValue" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

This is how we have worked in our project.

Comment: This gives me the same error, `root element must match the name of the section referencing the file, appsettings`

Comment: I have updated the answer, notice the change, appSettings is the root element of the separate appSettings.config file, which is referenced in main config file. Change the section as this and is should work for you.

Comment: And if you want to separate name "ConnectionStrings.config" instead of "appSettings.config", then follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556071/the-root-element-must-match-the-name-of-the-section-referencing-the-file

Comment: That's really helpful thanks, I've marked yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe!

```
<appSettings file="ConnectionStrings.config">
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the `root element must match the name of the section referencing the file, appsettings`. I think it means that CrystalImageCleaner options are not connection strings.